# Can you program APIs?

Tags: api

I got the following question during an interview.

"Can you program APIs?"

Could you please explain what it means in an easy way ?
It's like a developer's job? 
For example, the functions in `AdMob SDK` that is exposed to publisher like `loadad()`, `displayad()`, these kind of method is `API`?

Can you please also give me an example for web?

It would be easier if you mention google's product.

Answer (score 0):

An `API` or *application programming interface* is an Interface of your software, which is used by other people. To say it stupid, they ask you if you can Programm.... An `API` can be everything with a defined Interface which can be used by other people.

**For example a REST-API:**

You write an XaaS-Service and want to sell it to a customer which use your Software you wrote. That he can use it you define CRUD-Calls for your program which the Customer can use. Now you have write a REST-API for your customer.

The Question can you write a `API`, is in my Opinion not from a Developer or someone in the Business. It´s like can you program and document your state...

Here is the [StackOverflow-REST API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) for a better understanding what I talking from.